# Videojs new skin and two vjs-control-bar

Tags: video.js

I'm searching to create a new videojs skin from scratch. 
Why there are two "vjs-control-bar"? how I use the first or the second?

Comment: There is only one `vjs-control-bar` in a default player. [Example](http://output.jsbin.com/yuhayuteha).

Comment: Actually, I made some tests: it has 2 control bars if I do    `videojs(rendered_dom, { 'children' : { 'ControlBar' : { 'children' : { 'muteToggle' : false } } }, self.on_player_ready);` [look](http://output.jsbin.com/manasuyeda)

Comment: `controlBar` with a small 'c'. Your example adds a new instance of control bar, rather than modifying the default one.  [Example](http://output.jsbin.com/mumulotesu/1)